# NuGet references, VS2015 and VS2013 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

We're just dipping our toes into the VS 2015 water. Our references to internal NuGet packages seemed to be a pickle so I forced a reinstall on one particular package.

It reinstalled it, and all its dependencies, for the whole solution. Afterwards, the `.csproj` files are missing their traditional references.

For example, this block/element existed in the project file before I updated:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

My guess is that this is new behaviour, that now all references are NuGet packages. I actually thought this was only for new ASP.NET projects, these are old ASP.NET projects, so I didn't expect this new behaviour (if that's what it is).

Is this new behaviour? Will all the team now have to move to VS 2015 because the refs will be missing if I commit these changes and they open it in 2013?

Thanks

Update: No response (Christmas) so x-posted at GitHub

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1866

Comment: When you say "missing their traditional references" what exactly do you mean? Are references to all non-Nuget assemblies missing? What happens if you add one back using "Add Reference"?

Comment: Updated the question with example of missing XML, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question here: no, this is not how it should work; reference elements are not removed from the XML in the `.csproj` file.